# Nhibernate to return Json with list

Tags: c#, json, nhibernate

I have a problem with my C# code. I can't produce my JSON well.

I'm using NHIBERNATE to connect and select data from my SQL Server. I want to produce a JSON with a list object inside it. Need your help guys.

NHibernate code:

```
 var query = (from partners in session.Query<Partners>()
             join partnerUsers in session.Query<PartnerUsers>() on partners.PartnerId equals partnerUsers.PartnerId
             where partners.PartnerId == partnerId
             select new Partnersss
             {
                 PartnerId = partners.PartnerId,
                 PartnerName = partners.Name,
                 PartnerUsers = new PartnerUsersss()
                 {
                     LoginId = partnerUsers.LoginId
                 }
             }).ToList<object>();
return query;
```

Class:

```
public class PartnerUsersss
{
    public int PartnerUserId { get; set; }
    public string LoginId { get; set; }
}

public class Partnersss
{
    public int PartnerId { get; set; }
    public string PartnerName { get; set; }
    public PartnerUsersss PartnerUsers { get; set; }
}
```

JSON result:

```
{
    "Data": "",
    "data": [{
        "PartnerId": 1,
        "PartnerName": "ExpressPay",
        "PartnerUsers": {
            "PartnerUserId": "0",
            "LoginId": "a@a.com"
        }
    }, {
        "PartnerId": 1,
        "PartnerName": "ExpressPay",
        "PartnerUsers": {
            "PartnerUserId": "0",
            "LoginId": "b@b.com"
        }
    }],
    "ResponseCode": "0",
    "ResponseMessage": "Successful"
}
```

But I want to be able to produce this JSON instead:

```
{
    "Data": "",
    "data": [{
        "PartnerId ": 1,
        "PartnerName": "ExpressPay ",
        "PartnerUsers": [{
            "partnerUserId": "0",
            "loginId": "a@a.com"
        }, {
            "partnerUserId": "0",
            "loginId": "b@b.com"
        }]
    }],
    "ResponseCode": "0",
    "ResponseMessage": "Successful"
}
```

I tried using List with this kind of code

```
PartnerUsers = new List<PartnerUsersss>
```

and also change the class. But I got an error

> List does not contain a definition for LoginId

In new class:

```
public List<PartnerUsersss> PartnerUsers { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove join from your query and modify your query like below,

```
var query = (from partners in session.Query<Partners>()
                     where partners.PartnerId == partnerId
                     let partnerUsers = (from pu in session.Query<PartnerUsers>()
                                         where pu.PartnerId == partners.PartnerId
                                         select pu).ToList()
                     select new Partnersss
                     {
                         PartnerId = partners.PartnerId,
                         PartnerName = partners.Name,
                         PartnerUsers = partnerUsers
                     }).ToList();
```

You need to change the type of `PartnerUsers` property to List,

```
public List<PartnerUsersss> PartnerUsers { get; set; }
```

Comment: Hi @er-mfahhgk

I tried using and modified that code. But, I can't figure out how to use the 2nd table which is in let keyword. May I have a little more help? Thank you!

And also, I change my property to List

Comment: You dont need to use it manually, the data in "let partnerUsers =...." is used at "PartnerUsers = partnerUser" means your "PartnerUsers" property contains all data in "let partnerUser = ...."

Comment: Hi @er-mfahhgk! I update the question. May I have your help again? Thank you so much!

Comment: Where this "tablePartner", "D_Partners", "D_PartnerUsers"  comes?, i think its should be "partnerUsers", "Partners" and "PartnerUser". Please show the the model class for  all above three